# Lucas-Kanade Least Square what does the b stand for in the equation?

Tags: computer-vision, equation

```
A^T Av = A^T b
```

What is the `b` in this equation of *Lucas-Kanade*, is it the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is the partial derivative of the image with respect to time.